# WCF Session ASP.NET Hosting Issue

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I am building a WCF service that speaks to an existing application, and this application requires access to ASP.NET sessions - the ability to see sessions is a requirement I cannot get around.

I built the WCF project - and have the following setting in App.config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
     <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

I also included an interface and an implementation of the service in the file.  In front of the implementation I have:

```
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =
    AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class SearchService : ISearchServiceInterface
{
```

This is a REST service, so my interface starts like:

```
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISearchServiceInterface
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string LoginToWebService_POST(Altec.Framework.Authorization auth);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetTopLevelFolderName_POST();
```

The service itself is hosted in another web application - in a SearchService.svc file which has this:

```
<%@ServiceHost language=c# Debug="true" Service="Altec.UI.Web.SearchService.SearchService" %>
```

and I added this to the web.config of the hosting application:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
      <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

I believe I did all the right steps - and yet when I try to run the web application I get this error:

> "
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: This service requires ASP.NET
>   compatibility and must be hosted in IIS.  Either host the service in
>   IIS with ASP.NET compatibility turned on in web.config or set the
>   AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute.AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode
>   property to a value other than Required.    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetEnvironment.ValidateCompatibilityRequirements(AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode
>   compatibilityMode)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute.System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior.Validate(ServiceDescription
>   description, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.ValidateDescription(ServiceDescription
>   description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription
>   description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnBeginOpen()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
>   at Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.OpenService(ServiceInfo
>   info)"

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- database connection details -->

  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1048576"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <location path="Scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Content">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="jQuery-UI-layout.css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
      <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
      <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISearchServiceInterface" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://vmwarren27dev.altec-wa.com/Altec.UI.Web.Portal/SearchService.svc/WCPService" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ISearchServiceInterface" contract="SearchService.ISearchServiceInterface" name="WSHttpBinding_ISearchServiceInterface">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="Altec.UI.Web.SearchService.SearchService">
        <endpoint address="RESTService" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="json" contract="Altec.UI.Web.SearchService.ISearchServiceInterface">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <endpoint address="WCPService" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Altec.UI.Web.SearchService.ISearchServiceInterface">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="json">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="AjaxControlToolkit" publicKeyToken="28f01b0e84b6d53e" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.51116.0" newVersion="4.1.51116.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned App.config - it sounds like your service is a WCF Service Library, that you're hosting under IIS.  If that's the case, you need to copy the WCF configuration section from the App.config to the Web.config of the IIS application that is hosting your service.

Libraries don't use config files - they use the config file of the calling application.

Comment: Right I did do that - I'll edit to add the full web.config above.

Comment: Is the web.config you updated the one for the application with the service file, or the application calling the service?

Comment: The application calling the service.

Comment: Put the settings in the Web.config of the IIS application that has the service file - it is that application (under IIS) that will need the AspNetCompatabilityEnabled set to True.

Comment: I did. It's still the same issue.